# How do I show that the given group has order $16$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with presentation $\left<a,b \ \middle|\  a^8=b^2=1, ab=ba^3\right>$.

I have shown that every element of $G$ is of the form $b^i a^j$ where $0\leq i \leq 1$ and $0\leq j\leq 7$.

However, I'm stuck in proving that there are exactly $16$ elements. That is, how do I prove that $b^i a^j = 1$ iff $i=j=0$?

Comment: if you have 2 possible values for $i$ and 8 possible values for $j$, you have $2*8=16$ values of $b^ia^j$.

Comment: @BrunoVieiraCosta No. To assert that $b^ia^j$'s must be mutually distinct. And that is the question I'm asking.

Comment: You can use $ab=ba^3$ repeatedly to move all the $a$'s to the end. That gives you $b^ia^j$. Then you use $a^8=b^2=1$ to deduce that you only need $i=0,1$ and $j=0,\dots,7$.

Comment: @almagest That is what exactly I have shown.. That does not answer my question.. In other words, i have shown $|G|\leq 16$. And my question is how to prove $|G|=16$.

Comment: All you need to establish is that there is a group with 16 elements satisfying these relations. Clearly there are groups with less than 16 elements satisfying the relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, $B=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. As $A$ has an involutory automorphism $x\mapsto 3x$, we can let $B$ act on $A$ and obtain a semidirect product $A\rtimes B$ of order $16$ satisfying the relations of the presentation.

Comment: Is it the only (or the best) way to prove this? That is, can we prove this not finding "an explicit group that can be embedded into $G$", so to bound $|G|\geq 16$?

Comment: The only way to prove that $G$ is not required to have less than 16 elements is to exhibit some group with 16 elements which satisfies the relations.

Answer (score 0):

You know G contains 9 elements, $e, a, a^2,...,a^7,b $, since it is taken $a^i \neq b $ for any $i $

Then we look at the interactions of $a,b$

We know

$ab=ba^3$

So

$a^2b=aab=aba^3=ba^3a^3=ba^6$
$a^3b=a^2ab=aaba^3=aba^6=ba$
$a^4b=a^3ab=a^2aba^3=...=ba^4$
$a^5b=...=ba^7$
$a^6b=...=ba^2$
$a^7b=...=ba^5$

There are 7*1=7 ways to form $a^ib$ and 1*7=7 ways to form $ba^i $, and we can quickly verify they are all present above exactly once.

So 9+7=16 elements in G

Comment: This only proves that there at most $16$ elements, which he knows already.

Comment: How is it possible to have less than 16 elements? If $b=a^i $ for some $i $, the only choice is $a^4$ since $(a^4)^2=e $.  But then $a^5=aa^4 \neq a^4a^3 = a^7$.  Group closure sort of limits the possibilities here.

Comment: You haven't proved that $a^5 \ne a^7$. You haven't even proved that the group has order greater then $1$. As others have said, the only way to do this is to exhibit a specific group in which the relations hold.

Comment: Okay then follow up question. The only way $a^5=a^7$ is if $a^j = e $ for $j<8$.  But if we're allowing for that kind of flexibility then the statement isn't even necessarily true. $b=a^2, a^2=e$ for instance would work and $a=aa^2=a^2a^3=a $. Or just $G=<e>$. Isn't the usual convention that $a^n=e $ is the smallest such n and that $a \neq e $ for any generator?

Comment: That wouldn't be a convention, it would be an assumption. $G = \langle a \mid a^4=a^6=1 \rangle$ is a perfectly valid group presentation, which defines a group of order $2$.

Comment: Ah I see my confusion, thanks. I thought it was implied in the notation.